# OpenJPA: Why SQL Trace goes to System.err?

Tags: java, openjpa

**Problem Description:**

I've decided to redirect System.err to a file:

```
System.setErr(new PrintStream(error.log));
```

OpenJPA Log setup:

```
connectionProperties.put("openjpa.Log", "SQL=TRACE, DefaultLevel=INFO, Runtime=INFO, Tool=INFO");
```

Now, for some reason not only Exceptions, but also my SQL Trace goes to that file.
Any idea how to redirect SQL Trace back to Console?

**Update:**

As recommended, I've tried to set OpenJPA to use log4j - line in persistence.xml:

```
<property name="openjpa.Log" value="log4j"/>
```

But it's immediately broke the openJPA enhance process:

```
openJPA_enhance.xml:26: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Priority
```

default openJPA_enhance.xml file:

```
<!DOCTYPE project>
<!-- see details: http://openjpa.apache.org/enhancement-with-eclipse.html -->
<!-- pass params:  -Dopenjpa.libs=../lib -Dbuild.dir=./build/classes -->
<project name="jpa_enhance_builder">
    <!--path id="openjpa.libs">
            <pathelement location="./lib/openjpa-all-2.3.0.jar"/>
    </path-->
    <path id="enhance.cp">
        <pathelement location="${basedir}${file.separator}${build.dir}" />
        <fileset dir="${basedir}${file.separator}${openjpa.libs}">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>
    <property name="cp" refid="enhance.cp" />
    <target name="openjpa.libs.check" unless="openjpa.libs">
        <fail message="Please set -Dopenjpa.libs in your builder configuration!" />
    </target>
    <target name="build.dir.check" unless="build.dir">
        <fail message="Please set -Dbuild.dir in your builder configuration!" />
    </target>
    <target name="enhance" depends="openjpa.libs.check, build.dir.check">
        <echo message="${cp}" />
        <taskdef name="openjpac" classname="org.apache.openjpa.ant.PCEnhancerTask">
            <classpath refid="enhance.cp" />
        </taskdef>
        <openjpac>
            <classpath refid="enhance.cp" />
            <config propertiesFile = "${basedir}/src/META-INF/persistence.xml"/>
        </openjpac>
    </target>
</project>
```

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd" version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="XXX" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
        <class>...</class>

        <properties>

            <!-- Recommended to disable this property, since we do JPA Enhancement during the build. See an ant script: openJPA_enhance.xml  -->
                <property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="unsupported"/>

            <!-- Caching. TODO: Optimize if needed during the testing phase -->
            <!-- We shouldn't use Data cache data at this moment.  -->
                <property name="openjpa.DataCache" value="false"/>
            <!-- The QueryStatistics can be accessed via PreparedQueryCache.getStatistics(). -->
                <property name="openjpa.jdbc.QuerySQLCache" value="true(EnableStatistics=true)" />
                <property name="openjpa.QueryCompilationCache" value="true" />

            <!-- TODO: Enable for OpenJPA 4.0 - Prevents caching the sequences -->
            <!-- <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="disableAlterSeqenceIncrementBy=true" /> -->

            <!-- enforce DBCP (build in) connection pool -->
                <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DriverDataSource" value="dbcp" />

            <!-- Use LOG4J -->
            <property name="openjpa.Log" value="log4j" />  

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Comment: I strongly recommend to use log4j or other logging library to handle stacktraces and outputs.

Comment: I've tried to use log4j, but it broke openJPA enhancement process (see the question update). I should probably start a new thread related to log4j, but I want to keep my original question as well.

Comment: I found that issue already resolved, so i hope you got control about exceptions. What's about this issue?

Comment: The issue is resolved. 1) I use Log4j to redirect the SQL Trace output to Console.  2) issue with OpenJPA Enhancer - I was missing the class path to Log4J